# I'm looking for a purchasing plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm in the process of creating a book shop with WooCommerce. We want to sell books as well as buy books. I just can't find a buy-in plugin, can you recommend something to me.

Comment: What do you mean with a buy-in plugin? With only woocommerce you can create a book shop. Are you talking about payment gateways?

Comment: No, I would like customers to be able to sell your products / books and us too. Once a shop is sold Sell and one is not sold.